# Синхронизация прокрутки родительского и вложенных контейнеров в ОС WIndows

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть разметка (см. схему).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При прокрутке общего родительского контейнера, если под курсором находится вложенный контейнер, тоже имеющий прокрутку, то сначала прокручивается он до конца, а потом опять возобновляется прокрутка родительского контейнера. На маке все так и работает,
но на Windows есть проблема: после того, как вложенный блок прокручен до конца прокрутка родительского не возобновляется. Чтобы это произошло нужно либо подождать пару секунд, либо слегка сместить курсор в любую сторону, тогда опять "подхватывается" прокрутка общего контейнера.

Как избавиться от этой проблемы?